# What is the complexity of external merge sort?

Tags: merge, time-complexity, external, mergesort

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#:~:text=External%20sorting%20is%20a%20class,usually%20a%20hard%20disk%20drive.) time complexity of external sort is given as follows

**(N/B).log<sub>(M/B)</sub>(N/B)**

where **N** is the total size of the data, **M** is memory size and **B** is the number of chunks in the memory. I can understand log part as we sort each chunk in RAM, however I could not understand the base of the log as **M/B**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On the german wiki page (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externes_Sortieren#Untere_Schranke) you find a helpful conversion.

Comment: Thanks @NightTrain, it has a very helpful graph!

Comment: If your question has been answered please mark the answer as accepted and also consider voting for all answers that were helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 1):

After the sorting phase the merge phase processes `m` runs in parallel therefore you get the base `m = M/B`.

Source: [wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

> M is memory size and ...

The confusion is due to:

> B is the number of chunks in the memory.

In the wiki article, B is the block size per chunk, so the number of chunks in the memory = M/B. The wiki time complexity is ignoring the fact that one of the chunks is used for merged output, and that the algorithm uses a k-way merge where k = (M/B)-1.